# How to load the US borders as a MultiPolygon in Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I have a problem where I'd like to be able to tell whether a geodetic point falls inside the US. I found [this great data source](https://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/), which has the US border, States, and Counties. States and Counties are given as `Polygon`s or `MultiPolygon`s, which makes it easy to call `polygon.contains(point)`, but the US border is given as a series of `LineString`s.

How can I join these `LineString`s together into a `MultiPolygon`? Doesn't order of the `LineString`s matter? There is no obvious ordering in the data.

Comment: What about [`shapely.ops.polygonize`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US outline .shps are linestrings because they don't encompass the entire US outline.

```
outline_df = gpd.read_file('gz_2010_us_outline_20m.shp')
outline_df = outline_df.loc[outline_df['TYPE'] == 'COASTAL']
outline_df.plot(figsize=(12,12))
```

[image: US outline from gz_2010_us_outline_20m.shp]

If you want to get a multipolygon, for all of the US, you can do this with the US States .shp.

```
states_gdf = gpd.read_file('gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.shp')
states_gdf['dissolve_field'] = 1
states_gdf = states_gdf.dissolve(by='dissolve_field')
states_gdf.plot(figsize=(12,12))
```

[image]

If you want to use a subset of states, you can do this.

```
states_gdf = gpd.read_file('gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.shp')

state_subset_list = ['California', 'Washington', 'Oregon', 'Texas']
states_gdf = states_gdf.loc[states_gdf['NAME'].isin(state_subset_list)]

states_gdf['dissolve_field'] = 1
states_gdf = states_gdf.dissolve(by='dissolve_field')
states_gdf.plot(figsize=(12,12))
```

[image: subset of states]

For a shapely solution, you can do this.

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.ops import unary_union
uu_mp = unary_union([shape(poly['geometry']) for poly in fiona.open('gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.shp')])

uu_mp
```

[image: unary union mp]

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Shapely alone? I'm installing geopandas because it looks like I'll need it at some point, but I'd rather not have a dependency on the .shp file too.

Comment: You can use shapely's unary union, https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union. See addition in answer.

Comment: Okay, I needed help plotting those https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353082/plotting-shapely-multipolygon-using-matplotlib, but it seems to work great.

Comment: For the record, the geopandas way, loading from the geopandas file, seems equivalent. I also tried loading my shapely polygons into a geopandas dataframe and dissolving that way, but that left a bunch of gaps between states.